# sharepoint 2013 - default CSS file not rendering correctly - Chrome thinks its an image?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On my SharePoint 2013 pages, I am getting the following message through the console...

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/css: "http://my.website.org/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css?rev=ox%2BqLd6WTqhn6d%2FMqf2BMw%3D%3D".
```

I'm noticing that this note is a response to me having jQuery 1.8.3 connected to my pages...How can I fix this?

This is the code on top of my custom page layout...

```
       <head>
            <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">-->
                <!--SPM:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>-->
                <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
                <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
                <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
                <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
                <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
            <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
            <link href="https://my.website.org/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://my.website.org/_layouts/15/1033/styles/OLD/Themable/layouts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://my.website.org/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/searchv15.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <link href="https://my.website.org/_vti_bin/spsdisco.aspx" rel="alternate" type="text/xml" />

...more stuff...

</head>
```

Comment: is that any of the images on your pages are not getting rendered correctly or any specific image that you have referenced ?

Comment: everything else is getting rendered perfectly.  I have all my images loaded from the style library.  But for some reason, this image out of /styles/themable/corev15 (a physical location???) is causing the warning in the console.

Comment: I've seen this before when creating composed looks...No idea what causes it though.